# Wordpress Update Question

Tags: plugins

I have one simple question
I need update every new update of wordpress script and plugins or i don't need update i ask because every this update can finish with some error ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Update. It is important. There are security fixes in just about every release, not just changes to functionality. The longer a release is in the wild the more time bad people have to figure out how to break in. Update.

If you are getting errors, [update manually](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6.1/wp-includes/general-template.php#L24).

If you tell us what those errors are (edit the question), someone may know a way to fix them.